# Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-cognito

I integrated my Angular application with AWS Cognito using `amazon-cognito-identity-js version 3.2.0"`.

While developing and testing on my local machine, it works fine. I receive three kinds of token from the server i.e. accessToken, idToken and refreshToken and these token works well.

I built the exact same code using `ng build --prod` and deployed it to a S3 bucket. Even now I get the similar 3 tokens, however on subsequent calls the server throws an error:

`400 Bad Request","error":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>`

I have checked and no where do I add any kind of extra space. I have kept my `userPoolId` and `clientId` in `environment.prod.ts` file and they contain no extra space.

On login, I am calling `https://mydomain.s3.my-region.amazonaws.com/assets/data/fake-booking.json`.

This throws error while this  is being called in app, while the same url if hit on browser returns the required json.

I have tried looking few related questions on SO but they couldn't solve my problem.

Can someone guide please.

Edit: Below is the code that is used for adding headers

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let fullReqUrl = '';
    if (req.url.indexOf('http://') > -1 || req.url.indexOf('https://') > -1) {
      return next.handle(req);
    } else {
      fullReqUrl = `${environment.baseUrl}${req.url}`;
    }
    const authToken = this.awsService.getAccessToken();

    let headers = req.headers;

    // set the auth token
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', authToken);

    const authReq = req.clone({ headers, url: fullReqUrl });

    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
      map(res => res),
      catchError(err => this.handlerError(err))
    );
  }
```